# Can't SELECT from database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to use prepared statement on login function to prevent SQL injection using the code below:

```
    function login($email, $password, $mysqli)
        {
            // Using prepared statements means that SQL injection is not possible. 
            if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, salt, phnumber, realname, age, sex FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1")) {

                $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
                $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
                $stmt->store_result();

                // get variables from result.
                $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt, $phnumber, $realname, $age, $sex);
                $stmt->fetch();
                 }
         }
```

Then comes the password part which is working fine.
then I created a test.php page and put this code in it:

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

It only prints `$user_id`, `$username` and `password`.
I can't recall `$email` or other data, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the code that places those items into the session?

Comment: Is your `salt` an email?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy What do you mean? I didn't get you.

Comment: @aldrin27 No it's not.

Comment: @aldrin27 Should I replace `print_r($_SESSION);` with `print_r($stmt);` ?

Comment: Yes please. And see the result

Comment: I got error `Notice: Undefined variable: stmt`

Comment: is `$stmt` global variable? If yes, then your function should have `global $stmt`.

Comment: It should be a global variable. But how can the function have `global $stmt`?

Comment: I think I'm getting somewhere. I added `global $stmt` in the function. Now when I `print_r($_SESSION)` it added `[realname] => [email] =>` they're empty and didn't yet recall other data like `sex` or `phnumber`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the mysqli variable from the function vars and use the global $mysqli only.

Allso you do not save the returned value's from the query to either session variables or an array.

Result to Session vars:

```
$mysqli = new MySQLi("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpass", "$db");

function login($email, $password){
    global $mysqli;
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, salt, phnumber, realname, age, sex FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
        $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result()
        $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt, $phnumber, $realname, $age, $sex);
        $stmt->fetch()
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['db_password'] = $db_password;
        $_SESSION['salt'] = $salt;
        $_SESSION['phnumber'] = $phnumber;
        $_SESSION['realname'] = $realname;
        $_SESSION['age'] = $age;
        $_SESSION['sex'] = $sex;

    }
}
```

Result to array:

```
$mysqli = new MySQLi("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpass", "$db");

function login($email, $password){
    global $mysqli;
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, salt, phnumber, realname, age, sex FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1")) {
         $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "email" to parameter.
        $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result()
        $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt, $phnumber, $realname, $age, $sex);
        $stmt->fetch()
        $userdata['user_id'] = $user_id;
        $userdata['username'] = $username;
        $userdata['db_password'] = $db_password;
        $userdata['salt'] = $salt;
        $userdata['phnumber'] = $phnumber;
        $userdata['realname'] = $realname;
        $userdata['age'] = $age;
        $userdata['sex'] = $sex;

    }
    return $userdata;
}
```

If your email value is empty the query will never work, so first you need to see that the email variable is passed properly to the function. Replace the function temporarely by this code(in your test.php page)

```
function login($email, $password){
    echo $email;
    return $email;
}
echo login($email, $password);
```

If that does not show any result you should find the cause of that first. If it does show a result, test the SQL query directly (with PHPMyAdmin etc...) or MySQL CLI.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, salt, phnumber, realname, age, sex, email FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1")) {

        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
        $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();

        // get variables from result.
        $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt, $phnumber, $realname, $age, $sex, $email);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $_SESSION["userId"] = $user_id;
        $_SESSION["userName"] = $username;
        $_SESSION["realname"] = $user_id;
        $_SESSION["email"] = $email;
```

Comment: Didn't work, still all I get is `$user_id`, `$username` and `$password` can't even recall `$email`